# With OpenLayers-3, is this possible to color an icon in KML?

Tags: openlayers-3

when I see a KML in GE, color icons is displayed fine, but with OL3, it does not appear.
there are means for displaying those colors?
thanks for your answer

Comment: Have you tried to go with the examples? http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/examples/kml-earthquakes.html or http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/examples/kml-timezones.html